# WordPress Lightbox jQuery issue

Tags: jquery, wordpress, lightbox

I am using the Light - Responsive LightBox plugin for my picture gallery here: http://inspiredworx-labs.com/sites/revoker/pictures/

But when I click on an image, I just get the dark overlay. It works fine using the default theme. I have tried deactivating all other plugins too.

I can't see what the issue could be?

Any help or ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: I think the soundcloud js is causing the trouble, you have JS errors because of it .
I did not look at you code to the end (it was blocked ??) but I think you aretrying to access iframe to another domain, which causes js errors and exceptions. tryremove the soundcloud widgets and see if it works ..

Comment: Tried deactivating the SoundCloud plugin; but still does not fix issue. Thanks for your help.

Comment: SOLVED: I took out Modernizer js and it worked!

Comment: good . I saw it was a JS error, but somehow I blamed it on the soundcloud ..

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED: I took out Modernizer js and it worked!